# Can the extlinks extension to Sphinx be configured to show the url?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I really like the fact that I can shorten URLs in the text using the [Sphinx extlinks extension](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/extlinks.html).  Here and there I'd like to be able to display the full URL in the rendered document too, without having to hard-code it in the text and risk a mismatch between what's displayed and what the link points to.  How can I do this while still using the extlinks extension to list my external links? ie: I know I can do it outside of extlinks, but having that block in the conf.py file helps to manage external stuff.

Inside conf.py:

```
extlinks = {
    'mySite': ('https://example.com/%s', ''),
}
```

Inside page.rst:

```
You can click :mySite:`here <>` to go to my site, <<< This bit is fine, shows a clickable "here"
which has this address: ???                       <<< How do I do this bit?
                                                  <<< I'd like to see: https://example.com/
```

Comment: Configuration and usage is shown on the link you provided.

Comment: Thanks Steve, and I've read it and experimented with all the different combos I can think of.  None gives the behaviour above.

Comment: Do you need multiple external links each with a unique URL? If not, then don't use this extension and use regular old reStructuredText syntax for a single external link and optionally use a replacement. If you do, then `extlinks = {'mypage': ('https://example.com%s', 'mypage ')}` and `:mypage:'mylabel </>'`. Note I cannot use literal backticks in comments, so substitute `'` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, but it's not what I'm looking for.  I do need multiple external links, and I want to show the URL itself, not the label.  Your suggestion above renders "my label" as the clickable link, instead of "https://example.com/" which is what I'm after.  The only way I've hacked around it is to either have two separate entries, one with the prefix of `None` for display purposes only, or to have the url listed as the prefix too.  Both involve writing the URL twice, so both are equally error prone ... ?

Comment: Using the same configuration, the following will do what you want (with the same note about backticks) `:mypage:'https://example.com/ </>'`.

Comment: Yes, but again that means writing the url twice - once in the text and once in the conf.py file.  Ideally - and to avoid hardcoding errors/out of date links etc - you'd write it once, in the conf.py file, and propagate to wherever you needed it?

Comment: Did you look into replacements?

Comment: @user2662404 does my answer fit your use case?

Comment: @AndreaGiudiceandrea No, sorry.  In the end I had to have two aliases, as there are instances where we want to build on the URL, and other instances when we want to display it.

Comment: OK, you changed your mind. But I think my answer answers your question ("I'd like to see: example.com/"), and you need only 1 extlink alias.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
extlinks = {
    'mySite': ('https://example.com/%s', None),
}
```

in conf.py

and

```
You can click :mySite:`\ `
```

in page.rst

should do the trick and you will display

```
You can click https://example.com/
```

with a link to `https://example.com/`

while

```
You can click :mySite:`here <>`
```

will display

```
You can click here
```

with 'here' linked to `https://example.com/`